# Why is zlib deflate() hanging?

Tags: c, stream, gdb, zlib, deflate

My issue is that my program hangs on use of zlib's `deflate()` function.

I first initialize my `z_stream`, as follows:

```
int setupGzipOutputStream(z_stream zStream) {
    int zError;
    zStream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    zStream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    zStream.opaque = Z_NULL;

    zError = deflateInit(&zStream, Z_COMPRESSION_LEVEL);

    /* error handling code to test if zError != Z_OK... */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I attempt to write data to my z-stream with the following function:

```
int compressDataToGzipOutputStream(unsigned char *myData, z_stream zStream, Boolean flushZStreamFlag) {
    int zError;
    int zOutHave;
    FILE *outFp = stdout;
    unsigned char zBuffer[Z_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH] = {0};

    zStream.next_in = myData;
    zStream.avail_in = strlen(myData); /* myData is a null-terminated string */
    do {
        zStream.avail_out = Z_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH;
        zStream.next_out = zBuffer;

        zError = deflate(&zStream, (flushZStreamFlag == kFalse) ? Z_NO_FLUSH : Z_FINISH);

        /* error handling code to test if zError != Z_OK... */
        zOutHave = Z_BUFFER_MAX_LENGTH - zStream.avail_out;
        fwrite(zBuffer, sizeof(unsigned char), zOutHave, outFp);
        fflush(outFp);
    } while (zStream.avail_out == 0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I call these two functions (with simplifications for the purpose of asking this question) as follows:

```
z_stream zOutStream;

setupGzipOutputStream(zOutStream);

compressDataToGzipOutputStream(data, zOutStream, kFalse); 
compressDataToGzipOutputStream(data, zOutStream, kFalse);
...
compressDataToGzipOutputStream(data, zOutStream, kTrue);
```

I then break down the `zOutStream` struct with `deflateEnd()`.

The `kTrue` value on the last compression step sends the `Z_FINISH` flag to `deflate()`, instead of `Z_NO_FLUSH`.

It hangs on the following line:

```
zError = deflate(&zStream, (flushZStreamFlag == kFalse) ? Z_NO_FLUSH : Z_FINISH);
```

I then tried using `gdb`. I set a `break` at this line, the line where the program hangs.

At this breakpoint, I can see the values of the variables `zStream`, `flushZStreamFlag` and others. The `zStream` variable is not `NULL`, which I can verify with `print zStream`, `print zStream.next_in`, etc. which are populated with my data of interest.

If I type `next` in `gdb`, then this line of code is processed and the entire process hangs, which I verify with log statements before and after this line of code. The "before" log statement shows up, but the "after" statement does not.

My question is: Why is `deflate()` hanging here? Am I not initializing the output stream correctly? Not using `deflate()` correctly? I've been banging my head on the wall trying to solve this, but no luck. Thanks for any advice you might have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your functions should take a pointer to a z_stream, rather than passing the struct in. Your init function is initialising what is effectively a local copy, which will be discarded. Then your compression function will have a garbage z_stream passed to it.

e.g:

```
int setupGzipOutputStream(z_stream *zStream) {
    int zError;
    zStream->zalloc = Z_NULL;
    ...
}

... etc.
```

It also looks like your compression function is not taking into account the null on the end of the string, so that might cause you problems when you try to re-inflate your data.

```
zStream.avail_in = strlen(myData);
```

Might want to be:

```
zStream.avail_in = strlen(myData) + 1;
```